# store singledimensional and multidimensional in same key:value container instead of Structure?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, .net-4.0, key-value, multidimensional-array

I'm wrapping up my ajax copy & paste with explicit error reporting.

The final `Function` `Return`s three `Key`s with three `List`s as `Value`s.

**psuedo**

```
Return New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Object)) From {
    {"duplicatePoints", UniqueErrorsReport},
    {"inexistentPoints", ExistenceErrorsReport},
    {"insertedRows", InsertedRows}
}
```

Two are `List(Of Object)`s and one is a `List(Of Array)`.  I hate doing the same thing twice, so I'd prefer not to use a `Structure`.

I acted all smart and thought by declaring a `List(Of Array)` rather than a `List( Of Object())` would let me slide since [`Array` descends from `Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (if I'm reading it correctly).  Nope, at least not the way I'm doing it:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Array]' 
 to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]'
```

Is it possible to avoid using a `Structure` and simply `Return` containers of both non-multidimensionals and multidimensionals as `Value`s in the same `Key`: `Value` container?

Comment: @FabianBigler avoid using a `Structure` and `Return` a `Dictionary`/`KeyValue` type container that has both multidimensional and nonmultidimensional containers as `Value`s

Comment: OK I reread it and I got it. Do you have more than three keys or always just these three?

Comment: @FabianBigler For this one, 3.  I prefer doing things inline unless if they're used more than once in code.  I'd definitely use a `Structure` if 2 or more `Function`s had to return a similar variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is it possible to avoid using a Structure and simply Return containers of both non-multidimensionals and multidimensionals as Values in the same Key: Value container?*

No, this is not possible. You have to convert your array to a list or your lists to array. 
This is like if you try to store integers and strings in the same List(Of String).
You can not have different datatypes in the same `Generic.List`.

---

Unless you have dynamic results I would try to avoid using a dictionary here, and rather use a custom, class (like below):

```
Public Class ErrorReport
 Public DuplicatePoints as List(Of UniqueErrorsReport)
 Public InexistentPoints as List(Of ExistenceErrorsReport)
 Public InsertedRow as List(Of InsertedRow)
End Class
```

**I would highly recommend against List(Of Object)**, because they cost you performance (boxing and unboxing) and the more important reason: it is prone to errors because you can not detect errors in compile time.

Comment: cheers. also make sure to watch my last recommendation. You should try to avoid List(of Object)